# connecting to mysql database using python script

Tags: python

Hey guys just a small question on this connection here. I wanted to print the output of the sql db using python which is currently successful but the output is not what i desired.

```
def query(conn):
    x = conn.cursor()
    x.execute ("SELECT Amount from Expenses")
for item in x.fetchall():
    items = map(int,item)
    print "The amount is %s" % (items)
```

output:
The amount is [15000] --> which is the concern here. I want to get rid of the square brackets in the output. Please help me out on this

Comment: `items[0]`?....

Comment: Hi Rakesh, didn't quite understand it. Please elaborate.

Comment: @BhargavMg items is a list "[]" these brackets in python means it's a list. In rakesh's comment he's trying to access the first element from the list.

Answer (score 1):

The response you are getting if for items which can be multiple and it return a list.

So you are getting `[15000]`

How can i get rid of square bracket.

simple `items[0]`

If you are expecting multiple value and want to get all just simple iterate over a loop.

```
for item in items:
    print item
```

Answer (score 0):

`fetchall` return you a list of tuples. You do not need map also. You can directly access the element using index.

**Ex:**

```
def query(conn):
    x = conn.cursor()
    x.execute ("SELECT Amount from Expenses")
    for item in x.fetchall():
        #items = int(item[0]) -->Use index to access the element. 
        print "The amount is %s" % (item[0])
```

Comment: Hi Rakesh thanx for the help, much appreciated. I actually used map since the int value was being appended with a long extension 15000L. Hence i used it to convert the value to a plain int. Can you please help me understand how even after removing that map command too the L is not appended to the output.

Comment: Because `L` is just a representation for "Long".